# No web access on Android 2.3.7

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, browser, networking

I have an *LG Optimus V,* rooted, with Cyangenmod 7.2.1 (BackSide-IHO) that has developed, lately, a weird network problem:

While on 3G (or wifi) every app on the system with the exception of the two browsers on the system work perfectly. The browsers, which are Opera and the "built-in" browser cannot get to ANY webpage. They act as though they have no internet connection. Whereas I can fire up an OpenVpn tunnel via WiFi or 3G and it connects fine. Every other network-using app on the system also works fine on either 3G or WiFi.

I have the "SetDNS" applet and have changed from Sprint's DNS over Google's with it. This change was LONG before this problem began.

As I'm familiar with Linux, I've poked around via `adb shell` to see if I can suss out the weirdness, but nothing jumps out at me. Everything I do at the shell command line having to do with the network works fine. It appears the browsers have *something* misconfigured.. I have no idea *what*...

Does anyone have any idea of what it could be, or what else I could test -- and how to get the browsers work normally again?

Comment: Do you have any proxies configured, maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! I forgot to mention I'd snooped around in both browsers to see if that was the case, but was unable to find any settings for proxies in either browser. I couldn't find any proxy settings in the basic Android settings either..

Comment: You might want to add these important facts to your question (simply hit the [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/45860/edit) link directly below it) :) A third place I guess we can exlude now is some proxy app you might have installed (there are several "http proxies" on the playstore which would only affect browsers, mostly, and some WebApps, maybe), as you would have remembered them by now. The system's proxy settings should affect all apps (they are mostly hidden in the "advanced" sections of their resp. APNs), so we can ignore them I guess.